# $\prod_{n=1}(1-x^n)^6=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{n^2}\sum_{n\geq1}(2n+1)^2x^{n(n+1)}-\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{n(n+1)}\sum_{n\geq1}(2n)^2x^{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, infinite-product

Using Jacobi's Triple Product Identity prove that
$$\begin{aligned} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-x^{n}\right)^{6}=& \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x^{n^{2}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2 n+1)^{2} x^{n(n+1)} \\ &-\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x^{n(n+1)} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2 n)^{2} x^{n^{2}} \end{aligned}$$

I found this identity in the article `COMPLETION OF A GAUSSIAN DERIVATION - JOHN A. EWELL` See the image below
[image] He wrote the proof for $|x|<1$. But if you see in the article `A SIMPLE PROOF OF JACOBI'S FOUR-SQUARE THEOREM - M. D. HIRSCHHORN` he used the identity without such constriants. See the image below
[image]

Then what will be the generalised proof of this identity. Also please make the proof simple. I have seen many proofs of Jacobi's Four Square Theorem but only this Sumple proof i understood as i dont know much that level mathematics

Comment: Why [no context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) (or, even worse, an [explicitly hidden](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3820673) one)?

Comment: Context added...now please give me the proof